# Hibernate Envers 'forEntitiesAtRevision' generates redundant subquery

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am using Hibernate Envers to audit entity changes. Entities and audit tables are stored in MySQL database. The solution works fine in most cases but I found a quite strange problem with that.

Let's say I have an entity state at a certain revision and I want to get the previous change for that entity. For that purpose, I have written the following method:

```
    public <T> T getLastChange(@Nonnull Object id, @Nonnull Class<T> type, long beforeRev) {
        List<Number> revisions = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager).getRevisions(type, id);

        return revisions.stream()
                .map(Number::longValue)
                .filter(rev -> rev < beforeRev)
                .max(Comparator.comparingLong(rev -> rev))
                .map(rev -> AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager).find(type, type.getName(), id, rev, true))
                .orElse(null);
    }
```

It works fine except the fact that `find` generates "too safe" query:

```
select *
from persons_AUD person_aud0_
where person_aud0_.REV=(select max(person_aud1_.REV) from persons_AUD person_aud1_ where person_aud1_.REV<=462864 and person_aud0_.id=person_aud1_.id)
  and person_aud0_.id=56591;
```

**I already know the exact revision!** How to avoid this subquery?? I just want

```
select *
from persons_AUD person_aud0_
where person_aud0_.REV=462864
  and person_aud0_.id=56591;
```

Currently, it causes hard performance issues on big tables.

Would appreciate any advice on how I can persuade Envers to use passed revision as an exact match.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to my problem.
`AuditReader.find` method uses `forEntitiesAtRevision` which always produce that subquery.
But after some experiments, I've noticed that another method `forRevisionsOfEntity` can do exactly what I want.
So I rewrote my query as follows

```
    public <T> T getPreviousChange(@Nonnull Object id, @Nonnull Class<T> type, int beforeRev) {

        List resultList = getEntityManager().createQuery()
                .forRevisionsOfEntity(type, type.getName(), true, true)
                .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(id))
                .add(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().lt(beforeRev))
                .addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().desc())
                .setMaxResults(1).getResultList();

        return resultList.isEmpty() ? null : (T) resultList.get(0);
    }
```

And now, instead of 2 queries, I get one:

```
select *
from persons_AUD person_aud0_ 
where person_aud0_.id=? and person_aud0_.REV<? 
order by person_aud0_.REV desc limit ?
```

which performs quite nicely even on a large table.

P.S.
The `AuditQuery` constructor is actually quite rich and powerful!
It is easy to modify the query in the required way.
Thanks.